# Passing an array via ajax to a php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm passing an array via ajax to a php.

```
$.post("send.php",{arr:arr}); //["one", "two", "three"]
```

How do I assign each value to an variable in php? I tried this but does not do what I need.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['arr']; $i++){
   $var+($i+1) = $_POST['arr'][$i];
}
```

expected $var1 = "one", $var2 = "two",etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to create a dynamic variable name. You'll have to wrap the `$var` with `{}` and concatinate with `.` to create dynamic variables.

```
 ${"var" . ($i+1)} = $_POST['arr'][$i];
```

Comment: @Bekki Don't forget to choose as best answer. ;)